# Convert Command To Subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, terraform

I currently have the following:

```
tf = Terraform()
tf.init()
tf.plan(capture_output=False)
approve = {"auto-approve": True}
print(tf.apply(capture_output=False, auto_approve=True, skip_plan=True,**approve))
```

This works quite well, but I need to put it into a subprocess. I've tried the following:

```
tf = Terraform()
tf.init()
tf.plan(capture_output=False)
approve = {"auto-approve": True}
subprocess.check_output(['tf.apply','capture_output','0', 'auto_approve','1', 'skip_plan','1','**approve'])
```

However, I receive the error: "'tf.apply' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Can I convert the above into a subprocess? And if so, how?

Comment: Do you mean a subprocess or are you trying to do that as a background or asynchronous task instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess` executes external commands. By contrast, you are trying to execute something like (but not quite) Python code. This fundamentally can’t work.

What you *can* do is create a Python script that contains your Terraform code and execute *that* via `subprocess.check_output`. However, this only works if the Python script is *complete*. You can’t jus execute a fragment as in your case.

For a minimal example of what you *can* do, take your original script, save it as `tf.py` and execute it like this in Python:

```
subprocess.check_output(['python', 'tf.py'])
```